# Blank select option in Form Output

Tags: php

All,
I have the following code to select some categories from Wordpress:

```
$args = array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'hide_empty' => 0   
    );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
```

When I print out the array, I get the following output:

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 4 [name] => Baseball [slug] => baseball [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 4 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 29 [cat_ID] => 4 [category_count] => 29 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Baseball [category_nicename] => baseball [category_parent] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 2 [name] => Football [slug] => football [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 2 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 4 [cat_ID] => 2 [category_count] => 4 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Football [category_nicename] => football [category_parent] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 1 [name] => Uncategorized [slug] => uncategorized [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 1 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 21 [cat_ID] => 1 [category_count] => 21 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Uncategorized [category_nicename] => uncategorized [category_parent] => 0 ) )`

Here is my foreach loop to display the contents of the array:

```
foreach($categories as $category){
    if ($category->name != 'Uncategorized') {
        echo '<option value="'.$category->term_id.'"> '.$category->name.'<option>';
    }
}
```

For some reason the foreach loop is adding a blank option in between the options that have a value. What would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the `<option>` with `</option>`:

```
foreach($categories as $category){
    if ($category->name != 'Uncategorized') {
        echo '<option value="'.$category->term_id.'"> '.$category->name.'</option>';
    }
}
```

HTML tags are always in the form:

```
<foo>...</foo>
```

with a few exeptions that don't requre a child elements or text:

```
<input>
```

or

```
<input/>
```

Comment: That was dumb on my part. Thanks.

Comment: we ALL miss these things :)